# WebBrowser in WPF still opening link in new window

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I want to create "In-Browser" navigating which whenever the clicked link will be popped out a new window (IE), I want it to cancel and navigating it on my browser instead. I have search and follow some of the guide but I cannot prevent the window to be navigate on its browser. Below are what I'm doing:-

[Link example.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22943.preventing-external-links-from-opening-in-new-window-in-wpf-web-browser.aspx)

XAML:-

```
<WebBrowser Name="HostWeb" Navigating="HostWeb_Navigating" LoadCompleted="HostWeb_LoadCompleted" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
```

CS:-

```
using mshtml;
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Guid SID_SWebBrowserApp = new Guid("0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            HostWeb.Navigate("https://www.booking.com");
        }

    private void HostWeb_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ProgressGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                if (e.Uri.OriginalString == "https://www.booking.com/content/terms.html")
                {
                    // Cancel navigation of this URL. This will be load into Generic List to find with LINQ
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    NavigatedURI = e.Uri.OriginalString;
                }
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
        });
    }
    private void HostWeb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            ProgressGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { ProgressGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; }));

            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)HostWeb.Document;
            Guid serviceGuid = SID_SWebBrowserApp;
            Guid iid = typeof(SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2).GUID;
            SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2 myWebBrowser2 = (SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2)serviceProvider.QueryService(ref serviceGuid, ref iid);
            SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_Event wbEvents = (SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_Event)myWebBrowser2;
            wbEvents.NewWindow += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_NewWindowEventHandler(OnWebBrowserNewWindow);
        });
    }

    void OnWebBrowserNewWindow(string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Processed)
    {
        Processed = true;
        HostWeb.Navigate(URL);
    }

    private void BrowseBack_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = ((HostWeb != null) && (HostWeb.CanGoBack));
    }
    private void BrowseBack_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HostWeb.GoBack();
    }
    private void BrowseForward_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = ((HostWeb != null) && (HostWeb.CanGoForward));
    }
    private void BrowseForward_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HostWeb.GoForward();
    }
    private void GoToHome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HostWeb.Navigate("https://www.booking.com");
    }
}
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa")]
internal interface IServiceProvider
{
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
   object QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid);
}
```

Second approach is I cannot complete it because HostWeb.ActiveXInstance; is not exist on SHDocVw:-

[Link example.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-to-capture-popup-window-in-webbrowser-in-c-sharp)

```
using SHDocVw;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WebBrowser_V1 axBrowser = (WebBrowser_V1)HostWeb.ActiveXInstance;
    axBrowser.NewWindow += AxBrowser_NewWindow;
    HostWeb.Navigate("https://www.booking.com");
}

private void HostWeb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ProgressGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { ProgressGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; }));

        HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument)HostWeb.Document;
        IHTMLElementCollection htmlElementCollection = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("A");

        //Set All Anchore Target As _self For Stop Opening New Window......
        foreach (IHTMLElement curElement in htmlElementCollection)
        {
            string targetAtt = curElement.getAttribute("target");
            if (targetAtt == "_blank" || targetAtt == "_top" || targetAtt == "_parent" || targetAtt == "Array")
            {
                curElement.removeAttribute("target");
                curElement.setAttribute("target", "_self");
            }
        }
    });
}
void AxBrowser_NewWindow(string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Processed)
{
    // cancel the PopUp event  
    Processed = true;
    // send the popup URL to the WebBrowser control  
    HostWeb.Navigate(URL);
}
```

Giving example of [Booking.com](https://www.booking.com/index.html) web, how to prevent opening new tab/ new window **before it goes pop out** and navigate it though current browser(open new tab/window in current page)?

**ADDITIONAL:**
Given booking.com page having 4 main menu [Accommodation, Flights, Car Rentals, Airport Taxis], when clicking neither one, it will popup and not hit the `HostWeb_Navigating` events.

Comment: Have you tried intercepting [the IWebBrowser2's NewWindow event](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22943.preventing-external-links-from-opening-in-new-window-in-wpf-web-browser.aspx)?

Comment: @MarkFeldman i have try it on my first code wrap. the link also navigate to the same page from your given link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22943.preventing-external-links-from-opening-in-new-window-in-wpf-web-browser.aspx).

You add a reference to COM->Microsoft Internet Controls and handle the `LoadCompleted` event:

```
static readonly Guid SID_SWebBrowserApp = new Guid("0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");

[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa")]
internal interface IServiceProvider
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
    object QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid);
}

private void WebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)webBrowser.Document;
    Guid serviceGuid = SID_SWebBrowserApp;
    Guid iid = typeof(SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2).GUID;
    SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2 myWebBrowser2 = (SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2)serviceProvider.QueryService(ref serviceGuid, ref iid);
    SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_Event wbEvents = (SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_Event)myWebBrowser2;
    wbEvents.NewWindow += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_NewWindowEventHandler(OnWebBrowserNewWindow);
}

private void OnWebBrowserNewWindow(string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers,
    ref bool Processed)
{
    Processed = true;
    webBrowser.Navigate(URL);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Source="http://booking.com" LoadCompleted="WebBrowser_LoadCompleted" />
```

Comment: your solutions is already apply based from my question on Link 1 example. What happen is it popped out the new window. I don't know much about web term where in WebBrowser WPF, it open new window. If I open in Opera browser, it will open in new tab. Is there any ways to capture the clicked link before it navigating so it can navigate though parent page?

Comment: it's work. But I'm wondering why the navigated page that linked, look like broken and uncomplete load? do you have any idea?